# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError with JNI

Tags: java

[image]

As you see here is the error after a few commands, the program works in Eclipse. Any ideas?

Comment: Does `java -Djava.library.path=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH sslarp.controller.Controller` work?

Comment: @guido Same error I'm afraid bud!

Comment: is libgetmapcip the JNI glue library, or the target library?

Comment: @guido I am currently trying to get Java working with C++. Trying to get this to work via libgetmacip.so. That is also trying to include a third-party library called libcrafter.so. Could it be that it is only including the one and not the other? Also glue and target? I am new to including .so files, it's all confusing!

Comment: read this: http://www.think-techie.com/2009/08/java-native-interface-jni.html

Comment: @guido Don't get me wrong, I've been through a lot of tutorials, they don't explain linking properly, here is the command I use for compiling `g++ -fPIC -shared -o libgetmacip.so -I $JAVA_HOME/include -I $JAVA_HOME/include/linux getmacip.cpp test.cpp -L/home/karl/workspace/sslarp/lib/libcrafter/.libs/ -lcrafter`

Comment: @guido I resolved the issue, by removing all the env variables and replacing it with one! I have another problem however which I will post!

Answer (score 0):

Cleared out the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and replaced it with one. The command:

```
karl@karl-vm:~/workspace/sslarp/bin$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/karl/workspace/sslarp/lib/
```